# SQL Server Delta Records Pulling

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-administration

In our SQL Server DB, we have about some 800+ tables and there are 40 - 50 tables are business critical tables. MIS team needs to generate reports based on those 50 business tables.

Those 50 tables gets updated frequently. MIS team requires those delta records (update/inserted/deleted)

What would be the best solution?

We have few approches here 
1.Always On 2.Replication 3.Mirroring 4.Introducing new column (LastModifiedDate & creating index) in those 50 tables and pulling those records periodically and populating it to MIS environment.

There will be huge code change for the new column LastModifiedDate approach.

Based on those 50 tables, we have huge number of stored procedures which it has Insert/Update

statements. In those stored procedures, we need to do code change for LastModifiedDate.

What would be the best solution from the above approches?

Pls let us know if any other approach to do. Note: We are using SQL Server 2008 R2

Regards Karthik

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to have insert, update and delete triggers on these tables, and for each table an archive table with exactly the same columns plus e.g. username, modifieddatetime and a bit to indicate new and old.  Then the triggers simply insert into archive select from inserted/deleted + current user, current time and 1 for inserted and 0 for deleted.

Then all your MIS need to concern themselves with is the archive tables, and you will not need to make a structure change to the existing tables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I hope trigger will not be the better solution.

Comment: @Karthik If creating 150 triggers worries you, I have a stored procedure that creates them automatically, which I would be quite happy to share!

Comment: Bro, Creating 150 triggers doesnt matters here. I can write script to create it. But the impact is very important, because it is critical database and has frequent insert/update. Trigger leads to problem i hope